# How can I use KDE filepicker dialog in GNOME apps?

Tags: gnome, kde

Is there a way you can use KDE filepicker with GNOME apps? I guess if I somehow trick the app into thinking it is running under KDE it will then use KDE filepicker. Am I right?

Comment: What's a "filepicker"? Do you mean the file browser?

Comment: @terdon: The "Open File" dialog uses by apps.

Comment: @terdon Yes as Florian said I mean the file selection dialog.

Answer (score 1):

The GNOME filepicker is part of the [GTK toolkit](http://gtk.org/) and stays the same no matter what desktop environment you use.

There is no way to use another filepicker other than programming your own and patching GTK to use it.

Comment: There was a tool for this  called KGTK http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=36077 but it is more of a hack, not a standard solution.

Comment: It doesn’t show thumbnails which is a big problem.